# Matlab Livescript Problem: Cannot control display of subscripted symbols in exponents?

Tags: matlab

The following code produces an unexpected output (R2022b MacOS Monterey 1.26, Symbolic Math toolbox installed). The output is unexpected because the output display equation seem to insist upon writing theta2 before theta1, which can really impair the usefulness of the displayed livescript output equation:

```
syms e theta_1 theta_2
disp(e^(theta_1 + theta_2))
disp(e^(theta_1 - theta_2))
```

the livescript displayed output is:

[image]

The first displayed equation is an unexpected nuisance. The second displayed equation is a real pain in the neck.

Is there any solution to this? I guess I could use LATEX but not really what I want to do. I could really use a good reference on the nuances of the many Matlab equation display commands.

Here is a screenshot of my display:

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce your output in MATLAB 2020a. Are you sure the code you posted generated that output? As it is described in your post, the issue is not reproducible. Please, edit your question providing more context, such as the MATLAB version and the actual code you used to generate the output.

Comment: Sorry my bad, picchiolu. I checked my code again and it is still working the same. i have updated the question to include R2022b, MacOS 12.6 Monterey, also Symbolic Math Toolbox installed. If R2022a displays something else, I think possibly I can download R2022a and use that. Matlab has at least three different rendering schemes (livescript window, latex in command window, command window, disp command) and they all work differently not only with respect to the displayed characters but also to the extent the characters are substituted with numeric values.

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot believe that ```disp(e^(theta_1 - theta_2))``` produces the second output you show in your question: MATLAB would have to basically invent the reciprocal of the exponent out of nothing! Please paste a screenshot of the LiveScript window where all this is happening. A screenshot where we can see both the source and the output at once. You either discovered a horrible bug or you messed up with the installation big time.

Comment: Picchiiolu, I added the screenshot that includes the entire environment. The second equation is mathematically correct because the exponent is simply negated in the transition from numerator to denominator. I would say that perhaps the "bug" is that the Matlab equation display logic prioritizes subscript "2" over subscript "1". The Matlab equation display logic will not do "xsub1 - xsub2". It appears Matlab insists upon "xsub2 - xsub1" and when this term is in an exponent Matlab is forced to flip it to the denominator. Mathematically correct buy highly irritating.

Comment: I think the culprit is in a preference you can set: I posted the solution in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `sympref('PolynomialDisplayStyle','descend');` before the `disp` commands. This will change the order with which the `theta` variables are displayed and will therefore affect the final output:

```
clc; clear all;
sympref('PolynomialDisplayStyle','descend');

syms e theta_1 theta_2;
disp(e^(theta_1 + theta_2));
disp(e^(theta_1 - theta_2));
```

which yields

[image]

On the other hand, using `sympref('PolynomialDisplayStyle','ascend');` produces the weird output you showed in your post.

More info about `sympref` [here](https://it.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/modify-output-of-symbolic-results.html).

Comment: Perfect, picchiolu! Thank you very much! I did not know "sympref" existed, let alone that it could fix this up:)